# Preventing and Re-enabling Windows Idle State

Tags: c#

The following code allows me to prevent windows from entering an idle state and my machine from locking itself:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern EXECUTION_STATE SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE esFlags);

public static void PreventSleep()
{
    if (SleepUtil.SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS
            | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED
            | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED
            | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED) == 0) 
            SleepUtil.SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS
                | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED
                | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED); 
    }
```

That works nicely, but what would I need to do to re-enable idle? I've been messing around with a few things, but each time I try, I have to leave the laptop for 10 minutes to see if it idles (my power options are locked by group policy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about saving the return value of your call to `SetThreadExecutionState`? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the previous thread execution state.

So it seems reasonable that you could write:

```
private EXECUTION_STATE SavedState;

SavedState = SleepUtil.SetThreadExecutionState(...);
```

`SavedState` contains the previous value. So it seems like you could put things back by writing:

```
SleepUtil.SetThreadExecutionState(SavedState);
```

You could even examine the return value (`SavedState`) to determine what the default is, and use that ...

At least, that's what I'd try first.

Comment: Only just had a chance to test this, but it definitely worked! Many thanks. As a side note, I removed the EXECUTION_STATE.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED flag as this prevented me from sleeping my machine. Now it will sleep and resume while continuing to prevent the lock timeout. Excellent :)